# Can I download my youtube videos through the oficial Youtube API?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

I want to download just my uploaded videos. But, I don't see anything in the youtube API documentation talking about this.

Can I do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby#retrieve_my_uploads

Comment: @khell I saw this link, but this is a upload video. I need the download

Comment: YouTube is the place to ask this.

Comment: You can only download them through the web, not from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officialy not because there's nothing in the API reference about this.

BUT:

There's a script for the chrome extension Tampermonkey, called [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki), which adds a download button to any youtube video when activated. I think this is possible through the html5 player, that has unencrypted (?) mp4 input files. So, when YouTube Center can do it, there has to be a way.
But I have no idea how to get there (And since the script has about 25k lines, i don't really want to find out how they make it) :)

So, if you really have to, you could use this unofficial way, but it only allows 720p, not the original file that was uploaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using an unofficial way. Thanks a lot for your time.